# Using Cloud Storage for Synchronisation

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing, cloud-storage

I have an application in mind which will be implemented as a number of compute heavy processes running on cloud VMs. The basic model is that all the processes see a shared data store containing many objects of sizes ranging from a few bytes up to terabytes. Each process runs jobs from some kind of shared queue (typically a job runs for at least a few seconds, and it might run for weeks) and each job reads some objects and creates some (the names of the objects it reads, and the names of the ones it creates are known in advance).  A job can't be started until all the objects it reads are available.  Some early experiments doing this on a local cluster over NFS failed because of poor consistency from NFS. Job A would write object O and then exit. The scheduler would see that A had exited that O was created, and start B on some idle computer and B would fail to see object O because of NFS inconsistencies.

So my question is , in the modern world of the cloud, what types of storage, or what properties of a storage solution, should I look at to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises due to the concurrent nature of distributed computing.  One processor may see a task as completed, but another may not, due to caching or other reasons.

In a real cloud storage system, such as Amazon S3, this issue will be greatly exacerbated.  These systems usually have an explicit "eventual consistency" model, which means if you upload something you'll eventually see it, but you don't know when.

The best way of handling it is in the processing software, rather than the storage system.  If a task is started and the prerequisite pieces of information are not found, wait for a while and try the task again.

Comment: I'm looking for detail of the specific consistency models inferred by specific systems.